# java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, nullpointerexception

I am doing a project HelpDesk chat with jsf 2.0 and primefaces, but an error is generated when I try to connect the Attendant or User in Chat.

In atendente.xhtml and index.xhtml have a form that sends the information to a AtendenteBean.java and UsuarioBean.java respectively file.

This is a page Atendente.jsp:

```
<p:panel header="Login of Atendant" rendered="#{not atendenteMB.autenticado}">
         <h:outputLabel for="txtNome" value="Login:"/>
         <br/>

         <h:inputText id="txtNome" value="#{atendenteMB.atendente.login}"/>
         <br/>

         <h:outputLabel for="txtSenha" value="Password:"/>
         <br/>

         <h:inputSecret id="txtSenha" value="#{atendenteMB.atendente.senha}"/>
         <br/>
         <h:commandButton action="#{atendenteMB.signIn}" value="Login"/>
         <br/>

       </p:panel>
```

---

This is the java file AtendenteBean.java:

```
@ManagedBean(name="atendenteMB")

@SessionScoped
public class AtendenteBean implements Serializable{

public AtendenteBean(){
}

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@ManagedProperty(value="#{localizadorMB}")
private LocalizadorBean gerenciarLocalizador;

@ManagedProperty(value="#{chatMB}")
private ChatBean chat;

private Atendente atendente = new Atendente();
private boolean autenticado;

public void signIn(){
    if(atendente.getLogin().equals(atendente.getSenha())){
        gerenciarLocalizador.getGerenciador().addAtendente(atendente);
        setAutenticado(true);
    }
    else{
        FacesMessage msgm = new FacesMessage("Login ou Senha inválidos.");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msgm);
    }
}

...
}
```

---

see the error generated when I press the Login button, please.

```
HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.NullPointerException

type Exception report

message
---
java.lang.NullPointerException

description
---
The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 
---
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)



root cause 
---
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpress    ionAdapter.java:101)
        com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:101)
    javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:786)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1251)
        com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)



root cause
---

java.lang.NullPointerException
    managedbean.AtendenteBean.signIn(AtendenteBean.java:34)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
    org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
        javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpress    ionAdapter.java:87)
        com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:101)
    javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:786)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1251)
        com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)



note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.47 logs.
```

---

Please, I need a help to solve this error.
If need more details, just communicate.

Comment: Please try to narrow it down first. Most peolple won't read through a stacktrace that's longer than the code, most people won'T even read through all your code. Find out first what file is causing what exact exception, and name the root cause with the stacktrace limited to the relevant parts.

Comment: atendente.getLogin() is null

Comment: Ok, you're right, I edited only for the relevant part. Sorry, I'm new here.

Comment: Prash, how I solve this problem in atendente.getLogin()? The error is in line 34, **gerenciarLocalizador.getGerenciador().addAtendente(atendente);**, but I don't know what metod is null. If is getLogin() or getSenha().

Comment: Why you didn't check it? Or add `atendente.getLogin() != null && ` in that line.

Comment: Lear how to use a debugger. Really, it's pointless to spend hours to try finding null pointers if it can be done within minutes. Set a breakpoint right where the error is and inspect your stack.

Comment: Just by curiosity, do you have a getter and setter for your `gerenciarLocalizador` managed bean? Also, which scope this managed bean has?

Comment: @JohannesH. this problem doesn't seem related to Java at all, but (wrong) usage of JSF capabilites, so using a debugger is not really an option.

Comment: Yes, have a getters and setters:
`public LocalizadorBean getGerenciarLocalizador() {
  return gerenciarLocalizador;
 }

 public void setGerenciarLocalizador(LocalizadorBean gerenciarLocalizador) {
  this.gerenciarLocalizador = gerenciarLocalizador;
 }`

Comment: @Luiz which scope this managed bean has?

Comment: This ManagedBean serves only to access my business class called GerenciadorHelpDesk. In this class I own my methods to add and remove users and the attendants in the waiting queue and manage the chat.

Comment: I mean what scopes has `LocalizadorBean`...

Comment: Solved, @Luiggi the variable gerenciarLocalizador was not instantiated and the object's constructor did not initialize correctly.